# Error Java.lang.StackOverflowError ¿Explicación?

Tags: java

```
public class Ejemplo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ejemplo ejecutar = new Ejemplo();

        ejecutar.asignarValores();
    }

    Ejemplo x = new Ejemplo(); // Aqui se produce el error

    String nombre;

    public void asignarValroes() {
        x.nombre = "Juan";
        System.out.print(x.nombre);
    }
```

El error por lo que estuve viendo sucede en `Ejemplo x = new Ejemplo();` por algo de '**recursividad infinita**', pero no me queda claro, ¿porqué sale ese error? ¿Porqué al instanciar ese objeto dentro del metodo **asignarValores**, si me lo ejecuta y no me sale error?

Comment: Amigo, te recomiendo que en vez de subir una imágen, puedes subir el código. Saludos!

Comment: Listo, ya lo hice

Comment: tu clase Ejemplo esta tratando de generar un objeto de tu clase Ejemplo? no entinedo nada d elo que intentaste hacer.

Comment: Estaba probando distintas cosas, el código no tiene un objetivo en concreto, pero en resumen, creo un objeto dentro de la clase, y en un metodo a parte le asigno un valor, hasta ahi todo normal, pero al ejecutarlo me sale el error del titulo

Comment: En la definición de la clase Ejemplo, creas una instancia de tipo Ejemplo que se entiende como un atributo de la clase, así que siempre que instancias a Ejemplo, se crea un atributo x de tipo ejemplo. Esta nueva instancia, a su vez, llama la definición que, por dentro, crea una instancia de tipo ejemplo. Y así, ad infinitum hasta que consume todo el espacio en memoria.

Comment: " Esta nueva instancia, a su vez, llama la definición " ¿A que te refieres con definicion?

Answer (score 4):

Verás, **al crearse un objeto del tipo Ejemplo este crea una instancia de él mismo**(*Ejemplo x = new Ejemplo()*). Que **a su vez crea otro del mismo y otro y otro**, de manera que nunca terminará de crear instancias. Intenta esto:

```
public class Ejemplo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Ejemplo ejecutar = new Ejemplo();

      ejecutar.asignarValores();
    }

    String nombre;

    public void asignarValores(){
        nombre = "Pedrito Celedonio del Rio detras de Mi Casa III";

        System.out.println(nombre);
    }
}
```

Comment: Y a que se debe eso? Porque se esta llamando infinitas veces? Entiendo un poco más de porqué pasa el error, pero no me queda del todo

Comment: mas que llamar al constructor, esta linea: Ejemplo x = new Ejemplo(); crea un objeto de si mismo, que crea un objeto de si mismo, que crea un objeto de si mismo, etc...

Comment: Y cual es la lógica para entender por la cual crea objetos de si mismo constantemente? , porque comprendo que se cree objetos de si misma infinitamente, pero no comprendo el porqué lo hace. Y porque en el main, que tambien creé una instancia, eso no sucede?

Comment: El programa que hiciste hace esto:
1.- En la función main crea un objeto de tipo Ejemplo(ejecutar)
2.- Al crearse el objeto(ejecutar) este crea otro objeto de tipo Ejemplo(x)
3.- El nuevo objeto(x) tiene otro objeto de tipo Ejemplo dentro(x.x)
4.- El nuevo objeto(x.x) tiene otro objeto de tipo Ejemplo dentro(x.x.x)
5.- La VM detecta que eso va a suceder hasta el infinito y lanza la excepción.

Comment: Okey, y porque en Ejemplo(ejecutar) no sucede eso?

Comment: Es que esa sentenica es correcta, la línea donde el flujo del programa se aloca(se pone a crear referencias infinitas) es en la declaración de x.

Comment: Porque de una manera es correcta y de otra no? Porque error de sintaxis no es, eso me parte el cerebro jaja

Comment: Es un error lógico. La sentencia es válida y ejecutable.